# Adding numbers in a string

Tags: python, string, sum, try-catch, except

I have a string as an input for the code I'm writing and let an example of the string be:

```
"12 inches  makes   1   foot"
```

My goal is to have my code run through this string and just pull out the integers and add them. So the output for the string above would be 13. I am using try and except in here as well since another sample input string could be something like "pi is 3.14".

```
msg= "12    inches  makes   1   foot"

thesum = 0

s= msg.split()

for a in s:

    try:

        if a == int(a):
            a= int(a)
            thesum += a
        print (thesum)
    except ValueError as e:


        print("Value Error: no int present")
```

I did what is above and I am not getting it to add the value of a (if it is an int) to "thesum". How can I get this to work? Also, I do want to have it in the try, except format so that I can call the ValueError

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to check equality with a string.  In fact, just try `'4' == 4` in an interpreter.  The answer is `False` because strings and integers are never equivalent.  Just put `thesum += int(a)` into the loop instead of your `if` statement.  If you don't want `try`-`except`, use `if a.isdigit():` instead of `try:` and take out `except:` altogether:

```
for a in s:
    if a.isdigit():
        thesum += int(a)
        print(thesum)
```

A good way would be the combination of several built-ins:

```
string = "12 inches makes 1 foot"
total = sum(map(int, filter(str.isdigit, string.split())))
```

`filter()` finds only the characters that are digits.  We then convert each to an integer with `map()` and find the total with `sum()`.

Comment: alright, I definitely am a fan of this format, but I'm new to exceptions and am trying to get the hang of using them, so I would prefer it in that format. Also I added a= int(a) before my if statement in my code above and now it actually sums the numbers up, but it prints everytime it adds a new value to thesum

Comment: @Nick: That's because you put `print(thesum)` inside of the loop.  If that isn't what you want, move it to the end of the loop and un-indent it until it is outside.

Comment: oh of course, awesome. One other question, now that I've switched it, it continues to print the statement I have for ValueError with each non-int value I have. How could I get it to raise that error only if the whole string doesn't have an int in it? For my 1st example string above when running it, it prints out : Value Error: no int present, Value Error: no int present, Value error : no int present , 13. All I want to print for that example above is just 13.

Comment: @Nick: I would define a variable before the loop with `valid = False`.  Then, within the `if` block, I would define it as `True`.  Then, move the `except ValueError as e:` to outside of the loop and change it to checking validity.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/GRb89tMj)

Answer (score 1):

`a` is `str`, and `int(a)` is `int`(if possible), so `a == int(a)` will never equal.

just add the value of `int(a)`, if the convert fails, it will raise `ValueError`.

The following codes should work.

```
msg= "12    inches  makes   1   foot"
thesum = 0
s= msg.split()
for a in s:
    try:
        thesum += int(a)
    except ValueError as e:
        print a
print thesum
```

Answer (score 0):

I like "re" and comprehension to make it easier to read:

```
import re
print(sum(int(a) for a in re.findall(r'\d+', '12 inches make 1 foot')))
```

Then you can extend the regular expression for floats, etc.

Comment: Using regular expressions here seems like a bit of an overkill when you have `split()`. If you want to handle floats, you can just use `isinstance(a, float)` or `import numbers` then `isinstance(a, numbers.Real)` to really cover everything.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the earlier approaches discount the second input which is "pi is 3.14". Although question has been asked with stated assertion of parsing integer. It requires treatment of numbers as float to successfully process second input.

```
import unittest
import re


def isDigit(s):
 return re.match(r'[\d.]+', s)

def stringParse(input):
 input = [i.strip() for i in input.split()]
 input = filter(lambda x: isDigit(x), input)
 input = map(lambda x: float(x), input)
 return sum(input)

class TestIntegerMethods(unittest.TestCase):

 def test_inches(self):
  self.assertEqual(stringParse("12 inches  makes   1   foot"), 13.0)

 def test_pi(self):
  self.assertTrue(stringParse('pi is 3.14'), 3.14)

if __name__ == '__main__':
 unittest.main()
```

Another take on the problem

Comment: This is super useful , thank you, I guess I forgot to mention that I'm just taking integers since my print statement for Value Error is "no int present". So in the case of "pi is 3.14", that expected output would be "Value Error: no int present"